# Passing dates to PHP through command line

Tags: php, linux

I want to be able to run a script via the command line and pass it a date for a function.

How would I go about doing this? I.e I need to pass it to a function within the file and pass it a typed date in the format. YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM Where the second MM is minutes not Month.

Would I need to use particular flags in the command or is there a simpler way?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

in your script?

**Edit**:

If you want to catch a parameter, you should use `$argv` array:

```
if (!isset($argv[1])) {
   die("You should give a date as first parameter\n");
}
if (!@strtotime($argv[1])) {
   die("The date you given is invalid.\n");
}
$date = $argv[1];
```

Comment: Because I want to pass it a user defined date